# Recompose withHandlers callback is not triggers

Tags: reactjs, recompose

I'm trying to exec a validation like this:

```
 const validateWithState = compose(
     withState('current', 'handleChange', {}),
     withState('isValid', 'validate', false),
     withHandlers({
        handleChange: ({current, handleChange, validate}) => () => {
              /* logic here */
              handleChange(current, () => {
                   validate() /* <--- here */
              })
        },
        validate: ({current}) => () => {
             /* this line is never reached */
        }
    })
 )
```

For some reason the `validate` handler never executed.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 const validateWithState = compose(
     withState('current', 'handleChange', {}),
     withState('isValid', 'validate', false),
     withHandlers({
        validate1: () => () => {
        }
     }),
     withHandlers({
        handleChange: ({current, handleChange, validate1}) => () => {
              /* logic here */
              handleChange(current, () => {
                   validate1() /* <--- here */
              })
        },
    })
 )
```

Probably we can't access in a function which is defined in same `withHandlers`. It's a bit redundant but we can access if we have previous `withHandlers`.

Comment: Thank u! I've found the answer yet but this is exactly what I was looking for!